# Creating new Module in Zend Studio (Zend Framework 2)

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-studio

I have been following the tutorial from Zend (http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=EerB9bTvqrY) however when I add a new Module in my project I can not navigate to it, are the instructions in this tutorial incorrect?

Basically when I add a new Module in Zend Studio to my Zend Framework project I can not navigate to it, my new module is called "deals". I navigate to localhost/dealproject/deals and I get error 404. When navigating to localhost/dealproject/ it loads the zend skeleton application page correctly.

Thanks for your help.

module.config.php

```
<?php
return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Deals\Controller\Deals' => 'Deals\Controller\DealsController',
    ),
),
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'deals' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                // Change this to something specific to your module
                'route'    => '/deals',
                'defaults' => array(
                    // Change this value to reflect the namespace in which
                    // the controllers for your module are found
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Deals\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Deals',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                // This route is a sane default when developing a module;
                // as you solidify the routes for your module, however,
                // you may want to remove it and replace it with more
                // specific routes.
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'Deals' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

);

Comment: Can you please show us your route configuration from the module.config.php of the module that causes issues :)

Comment: I have now posted module.config.php in the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good to me :). I posted something in an answer, hope it will help you resolve your 404 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me the route configuration looks correct and it should show results. What I noticed is that your base URL (`localhost/dealproject/`) for the ZF2 application is in a sub directory of the domain's root. As you probably know all the requests are mapped to the index.php of your application (`~/public/index.php`). This is done by some configuration in your `.htaccess` file (in the same directory).

In the example URL `www.example.com/blog` if `blog` doesn't exists as a folder under www.example.com's root you get a `404 Page not found`. However, the .htaccess of ZF2 makes apache call the index.php in the domain's root if no directory is found (this assumes you use the ZendSkeletonApplication).

Now, since your index.php is not in the domain root (`localhost/`) but in `localhost/dealproject/` and your .htaccess is (I assume) in `localhost/dealproject/` as well, when you call `localhost/dealproject/deals` apache is looking for a directory `dealproject/deals` since in `localhost` there is no .htaccess to prepare the necessary configuration.

I would advise you to make `dealproject` folder the root of `localhost`. This will enable you to call your route like this: `localhost/deals` and .htaccess and index.php will be processed correctly.

Hope this helps :)

Stoyan

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've enabled the module in `~/config/application.config.php`

```
'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    'Deals',
),
```

Comment: The module is enabled, Zend Studio added it into application.config.php when I created the module. As far as I can see everything is correct, is there something wrong with my Zend Studio install?